# Book ID: Technology World vs Magic World in a multiverse setting

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm searching for a book series (Sci-fi/fantasy) that could be from the 90's or later that I read a few years back, all I remember is the plot from the first book:

Two worlds - one based in technology and the other in magic send out expeditions to other worlds via portals to survey them for resources. The two teams meet up and the tech world team kills the magic world team, leaving only one survivor - a woman with psychic like abilities. A war between the two worlds develop, spanning the multiverse. 
If anyone knows the title/author, would appreciate a reply.

Comment: There are other novels that explore similar concepts.  You might also look into the Piers Anthony "Apprentice Adept" series (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept) and the Jack Chalker Well of Souls series (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_at_the_Well_of_Souls)

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like *[Hell's Gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell%27s_Gate_%28novel%29)* by David Weber and Linda Evans, even though it's from 2006. From Wikipedia:

> Sharona and Arcana are worlds in the multiverse which hold human civilizations. Both have discovered portals, which allow one to pass from one Earth to another, parallel Earth, which is almost always similar but uninhabited by sentient beings. Chains of universes linked by portals are called transit chains. Most universes have just one portal, or two; a few have three, and both civilizations have only found one with four.

And here's how the story begins with a bit more info than you can gleam from the jacket:

> [...]The story begins with a Sharonan company's survey crew exploring a new universe, which they discover contains eight portals in close proximity. One of the members of the crew goes to hunt by himself, and has a surprise encounter with an Arcanan, also from a survey crew exploring the universe (although his crew is part of a governmental military organization). Each one is afraid that the other will shoot, so they raise their weapons, and then one panics and fires (who fired first was never made clear). The Sharonian managed to stagger back to his crew and warn them before expiring; they immediately began to move back toward the portal they had come from.

Right now, there's only a one more novel in the series – *Hell Hath No Fury* – but there might be a third book incoming in 2016.

Here's the cover for your viewing pleasure:

[image: Cover image]

Comment: Linda Evans aka [Krystle Carrington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krystle_Carrington)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, sadly, no http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_Evans_%28author%29

Answer (score 3):

I think I read this exact book as well! I was looking for it too, and I found it through Reddit thanks to [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/6iy9qy/scifi_book_with_interplanetary_portals/). It's called *InterWorld*.

[image: Poster]

Here's the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterWorld) for the book.

Comment: It would improve your answer very much if you could explain why you think this book matches the description in the question. As it is, this doesn't explain why this might be the right book.

Comment: While the basic background sounds similar, the plot doesn't sound anything alike, since Interworld is based on the protagonist Joey and his many variants, the magic and tech faction are just antagonists.